# What is authenticator in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to read through the code of an open source project on GitHub and finding myself getting confused looking at a file.  What is "authenticator" in the below code, and where is it defined.  As far as I understand it is not defined as a class anywhere.  This is the project URL: [github repository](https://github.com/atech/postal/blob/2fdba0ceb5ec50b00e36fe7a186a27317ee7f04a/api/authenticator.rb)

```
authenticator :server do
  header "X-Server-API-Key", "The API token for a server that you wish to authenticate with.", :example => 'f29a45f0d4e1744ebaee'
  error 'InvalidServerAPIKey', "The API token provided in X-Server-API-Key was not valid.", :attributes => {:token => "The token that was looked up"}
  error 'ServerSuspended', "The mail server has been suspended"
  lookup do
    if key = request.headers['X-Server-API-Key']
      if credential = Credential.where(:type => 'API', :key => key).first
        if credential.server.suspended?
          error 'ServerSuspended'
        else
          credential.use
          credential
        end
      else
        error 'InvalidServerAPIKey', :token => key
      end
    end
  end
  rule :default, "AccessDenied", "Must be authenticated as a server." do
    identity.is_a?(Credential)
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a DSL function that comes from the gem `moonrope`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is "authenticator" in the below code, and where is it defined.

Regarding the "what" – `authenticator` is a method that's being called with a [positional argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Positional+Arguments) `:server` and a [block argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument) (the `do ... end` part).

The "where" is harder to answer due to Ruby's dynamic nature.

Here's what I would do without an IDE to find the method's source:

#### Clone the repo

```
$ git clone https://github.com/atech/postal.git
Cloning into 'postal'...
remote: Counting objects: 1139, done.
remote: Total 1139 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1139
Receiving objects: 100% (1139/1139), 2.09 MiB | 1.22 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (502/502), done.
```

#### Install dependencies

```
$ cd postal
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching https://github.com/unixcharles/acme-client
Fetching https://github.com/adamcooke/moonrope
Installing rake 11.3.0
Installing multipart-post 2.0.0
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
...
```

#### Launch [`bundle console`](http://bundler.io/bundle_console.html)

```
$ bundle console
irb(main):001:0>
```

Maybe it's a global function:

```
irb(main):001:0> method(:authenticator)
NameError: undefined method `authenticator'
...
```

Nope. But it's probably defined under some module, let's find it:

```
irb(main):002:0> ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).select { |m| m.instance_methods.include?(:authenticator) }
#=> [Moonrope::Action, Moonrope::DSL::BaseDSL, Moonrope::DSL::ControllerDSL, Moonrope::DSL::ActionDSL, Moonrope::Controller]
```

`Moonrope` ... never heard of it. Details, please:

```
irb(main):003:0> Moonrope::DSL::BaseDSL.instance_method(:authenticator).source_location
#=> ["/Users/sos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/bundler/gems/moonrope-f56a37b8f121/lib/moonrope/dsl/base_dsl.rb", 73]
```

It's a gem, let's open it:

```
irb(main):004:0> ^Z
zsh: suspended  bundle console
$ vi +73 $(bundle show moonrope)/lib/moonrope/dsl/base_dsl.rb
```

That looks good:

[image: Vim]

Comment: Thanks, this will help me debug in future.

Answer (score 2):

As Aetherus mentioned, it is from the gem `moonrope`.

Here's how to use it

**Getting Started**

To begin, you need to define an authenticator. An authenticator's role is to extract an "identity" from an API request. In this example, we'll be authenticating our consumers using a token that will be unique to each user. The example below demonstrates a very simple authenticator.

```
authenticator :default do

  header "X-Auth-Token", "The user's unique API token.", :example => 'f29a45f0-b6da-44ae-a029-d4e1744ebaee'

  error 'InvalidAPIToken', "The API token provided in X-Auth-Token was not valid.", :attributes => {:token => "The token that was looked up"}

  lookup do
    if token = request.headers['X-Auth-Token']
      if user = User.find_by_api_token(token)
        user
      else
        error 'InvalidAPIToken', :token => token
      end
    end
  end

  rule :default, "AccessDenied", "Must be authenticated as a user." do
    identity.is_a?(User)
  end

  rule :anonymous, "MustBeAnonymous", "Must be anonymous." do
    identity.nil?
  end

end
```

Let's break that down:

- The first line sets the name of the authenticator. In most cases you'll only ever have one which should be named :default. This will apply to all actions in your API.
- Next, we define a that the authenticator uses the X-Auth-Token header. We
  provide a description and example for documentation purposes.
- Next, we define that a InvalidAPIToken error may be raised when trying to lookup the identity for the request. We include a description plus a hash of attributes that should be returned with the error.
- Next, we define a lookup block which specifies how to lookup your identity object from the request. This is executed in the same scope that would be used for any action in the API. This block will either return the identity object, raise an error or return nothing. If it returns something, that will be used as the identity object and the request will continue. If it raises an error, the error will be returned to the user and the request will stop. It if returns nothing, the request will continue however there will be no identity.
- Next, we set a default access rule which is executed on every request to verify that the identity has access to the requested action. The default rule will apply to all actions however you can create others which can be chosen for specific actions or controllers. The block for this rule must return a true or false value depending on whether the identity satisfies the access condition. The second argument is the error code which will be returned if this condition is not satified for the request. The third argument is the description of the actual condition (for documentation).
- Finally, we define an anonymous rule which can be used for any actions where there should not be any identity provided.

Here's a link to provide more information on the usage. [moonrope authentication](https://github.com/adamcooke/moonrope/blob/master/docs/authentication.md)

Comment: Please post the relevant sections of the answer here itself instead of posting the link. Links might change over time.